# Why Can't I Delete this Record (Table Constraints) - I am using Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am having problem deleting a record from my database table. I get Constraintviolation exception. I'm dealing with **Categories** and **Sub-categories**. I have a `Category` class that has **parent** which also refer to the same `Category` class. Categories with no `parent` will have the parent field be `null`. In the table below all empty parent columns means those categories are parent categories.

I am using Spring boot and Spring data so the repository and the `delete()` methods are created automatically. I just call the `delete()` method in my controller class.

I have the following class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="category")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id = IdGenerator.createId();

    @Column(name="name", nullable=false, unique=true)
    @Size(min=2, max=60, message="LATER")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne//(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent", nullable=true)
    private Category parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    private Set<Category> children = new HashSet<Category>();

  //GETTERS AND SETTERS HERE
}
```

and the following table ::

```
CREATE TABLE category(
    id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    parent varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES category (id)
);
```

with the following records in the table::

```
id      name            parent
1       Furnitre    
2       barbecue        1
3       Home and Garden     
4       Fashion         3
5       Restaurants     3
```

Now when i try to delete record 5 (Category record in row 5) i get

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`grabone`.`category`, CONSTRAINT `category_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`))
```

I think this shouldn't be the case because record 5 has no children and i have to be able to delete it.

What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

This is my controller code to delete `Category`. There is something rare going on here ::

```
@DeleteMapping(value = DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable("categoryId") String categoryId){
        Category cat = categoryService.findById(categoryId);
        categoryService.delete(cat);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

The above code works now. It deletes `Category` from the table but the following don't. It generates the above Exception. WHY?

```
@DeleteMapping(value = DELETE)
        public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable("categoryId") String categoryId){

            categoryService.delete(categoryId);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("", HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

In Spring Data repository, there are two delete() methods::

```
void delete(String id);
void delete(Category category);
```

One that takes `id` and the other that takes the `Object` of the class. Why is it that the one that takes the `id` doesn't work?

Comment: Given the message, I'd say that either you're not deleting the category 5, or the data is not what you claim it is.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for your comments. I have updated my question a little bit base on your comments. There are two delete() methods in the Spring Data. At the moment one works and the other doesn't. have an idea why it is so?

Comment: Which version of spring data jpa do you use? Because the method to delete a record by id is deleteById()